# Origin of $j$-invariant

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

It is often asserted that the $j$-invariant was first introduced by Felix Klein. Is there any evidence for this claim? What works of Felix Klein do deal with it? What is the origin of the symbol $j$ used for it? Where it had first appeared?

Comment: Related: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/origin-of-kleins-j-invariant

Answer (score 5):

Felix Klein, [Über die Transformation der elliptischen Funktionen und die Auflösung der Gleichungen fünften Grades](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02297507.pdf), Math. Ann. **14**,‎ 111-172 (1878-1879).

There is also a slightly earlier brief note in Italian, [Sull' equazioni dell' Icosaedro nella risoluzione delle equazioni del quinto grado](https://archive.org/details/RendicontiIstitutoLombardoS2V10/page/n279), Rendiconti Reale Istituto Lombardo, Serie 2, vol. 10, p. 253-255‎ (1877).

[image]

Dedekind may have gotten there first, see [Dedekind or Klein](http://macos.ua.ac.be/~lebruyn/LeBruyn2012a.pdf) (p. 67).

Notation: Klein used capital $J$, there is a factor 1728 difference with the $j$-invariant. ([Read more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531532/why-1728-in-j-invariant) about the origin of this factor.)

Comment: And other sources suggest Hermite (around 1850) or even Gauss... https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7628/what-is-the-modern-interpretation-of-gausss-summatorische-function surely it must be in one of Euler's collected works (...JK).